# concatenating two word embedding files in word2vec

Tags: python-3.x, word2vec

I have words embedding and POS embedding of the same corpus in word2vec.how do I concatenate them? for example if word embedding is of 100 dim and POS is also of 100 dimensions how do I combine to get total of 200 dim.

Comment: In what format(s) are your existing word-vector models?

Comment: Its in binary format..

Comment: Can you be more specific? How was it created, and how are you loading it, and how does your code access/use the non-concatenated versions?

Comment: I tried following this way:
step 1: => get word2vec for corpus
step 2: pos tagger for our corpus
step 3: get word2vec for our pos tagger of corpus
step 4: concat word2vec and pos of word2vec

Comment: fileName = "../data/ag_news_csv/train.csv"
    word2Vector = w2c.Word2Vec(fileName)
    # get class dict
    dictClass = word2Vector.buildClassDict()
    # get w2 model
    w2vModel = word2Vector.buildModel()

    # get pos model
    w2vPosModel = word2Vector.buildPosModel()

    new_word2Vec = np.concatenate((w2vModel, w2vPosModel), 1)


    # Initial classification
    cnnClassifer = cnn.CNNClassifier(wvmodel= new_word2Vec, classdict=dictClass, n_gram=1)

Comment: You can edit your question to include the extra details, well-formatted, for clarity. You should make it clear what libraries you're using. (For example, what's `w2c`?) There are numpy methods for concatenating arrays-of-vectors like you want – but given that the raw arrays are wrapped in library-specific word2vec-models, extra steps are likely necessary, dependent on the library details that still aren't clear.